# add banner is not loading second time using mopub sdk for android (4.0.4 ICS)

Tags: android, sdk, mopub

I am using mopub sdk for advertise in one of my application ,I have tested in other version 4.1 and 4.2  it is working fine but for android 4.0.4 (ICS  device: Micro max canvas ) add load when application first time launch . after second time it is not working. i have checked that api call for add is also hit to server and Response (html )also coming at device side but it is not displaying on device .  It is only i found in 4.0.4  how to resolve this compatability issue.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is device specific issue(It may be issue in micro max custom build OS for this version for above version it works) .After ICS , 4.1 to 5.0 all supports not show any issue on the other devices.